# opentok angular 6 error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

**ERROR in node_modules/@opentok/client/dist/js/opentok.d.ts(203,77): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise' requires 1 type argument(s).**

```
npm version: 6.2.0
node: v8.10.0
ng: Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 8.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.0.0-beta.5
@opentok/client": "^2.14.8
```

Comment: Could you consider posting a _[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_? It also seems likely that this is probably a bug; please consider reporting this issue at the respective repository.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify return value type:
`let p: Promise<boolean>`

Comment: Its opentok package file, i am not using promise in my any components.

Comment: node_modules/@opentok/client/dist/js/opentok.d.ts, Error comming from this file, its working on local system. when i do on production so getting this issue.